# VS2010 crashes periodically with System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I get the following error in the Activity Monitor Log.xml file

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range. at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CSS.ICSSLineTokenizer.TokenizeLine(ICSSTokenFactory
>   factory, Int32 lLine) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CSS.Implementation.CSSColorizer.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.IClassifier.GetClassificationSpans(SnapshotSpan
>   trackingSpan) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Classification.Implementation.ClassifierTagger.d_*0.MoveNext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.Implementation.TagAggregator`1.d*_16.MoveNext()

In source column, it says "Editor or Editor Extension"

This does not happen everytime, but on an average of once per day. If I restart it, all is fine. This happens at any part of the code, be it a css file or a cs or aspx. Can anyone help?

Subsequent to this, I got the below Resharper error in the Activity monitor xml file.

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>             C:\Program Files\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.0\Bin\JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.VisualStudio.v11.dll

AND

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>             C:\Program Files\JetBrains\ReSharper\v7.0\Bin\JetBrains.Platform.ReSharper.VisualStudio.v11.dll

Guys, I am not an expert programmer, just a beginner and am new to StackOverFlow also. So please pardon if I am posting at the wrong place or site. If anyone can be kind enough to state it too..\thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArgumentException isn't your fault; that indicates a bug in either Visual Studio or some extension you have installed. Make sure you've installed the Service Pack and all updates.

The JetBrains issue implies you have a version of ReSharper installed that supports Visual Studio 2012. As long as Resharper is working for you, I'd hazard a guess that such an exception is normal during startup if you're running an older version of VS than the highest version that Resharper supports.

Comment: Thanks. I have already installed all the updates and the SP1. Will try and re-install the SP1 again.